# How to embed all channel videos from YouTube without a proper user ID

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, youtube

How to embed all channel videos from YouTube without a proper user ID?

I already know that it is possible to embed all videos from a YouTube User's account like so (example, not my account):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=techcrunch" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, please notice that in the example above the user has a proper user ID (techcrunch). In my case I am seemingly not so lucky. Both my User ID and Channel ID are random strings of digits:

YouTube User ID: dEti36s42cHXXXXCroPGVA (example)

YouTube Channel ID: UCdEti36sXXXXELTpCroPGVA (example)

How can a user such as I, without a proper user ID, embed all of my videos as I have shown in the example above?

Vesa

Comment: Your example seems to be broken, or you forgot to include it.

Comment: Updated and corrected

Comment: Anyone knows the answer to this? Is there a solution available?

Comment: What happens when you replace KerryWongBlog with your Channel ID?

Comment: We are supposed to use the User ID, not the Channel ID when embedding the iframes. In any case, I have tried both just to be certain and they both generate an error message. The player shows up but it won't load any videos, rather it will just say "an error occurred please try again later"

Answer (score 1):

Right, if I understand this correctly, you want a username/userID, given a channelID. To do so, you're going to have to connect to the Google+ API, use [status.isLinked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#status.isLinked) to check if that channelID is connected to a G+ account, and call [contentDetails.googlePlusUserId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId) to retrieve the username, which will be placed in the iframe's src. I'd suggest reading up on the [YouTube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

Edit:

- Username: KerryWongBlog
- UserID: dEti36s42cHXXXXCroPGVA
- ChannelID: UCdEti36sXXXXELTpCroPGVA

http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=USERNAME_GOES_HERE

You want the **username**, given the **channelID** or the **userID**. The wording here is important. What you call a "proper User ID" it called a "username".

Comment: But I have a User ID already (see above). Are there several types of User ID's? Also: How come the guy in the example above has a proper user ID based on real words, while I just have a random string of digits?

Comment: Trying to straighten things out

Comment: You want to get the username, given the userID or channelID. The username is what's going to allow you to embed a playlist. The functions I mentioned should return the username.

Comment: Actually, I think I made a kind of typo in the original question. I changed the wording from "user has a proper user name" to "user has a proper user ID" now.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think the username would help. It is probably the user ID that is required to embed the channel videos, not the user name.

Comment: Here's another example. If you browse to https://www.youtube.com/user/techcrunch you will see the content of the user techcrunch but if you browse to my user ID https://www.youtube.com/user/dEti36s42cHELTpCroPGVA nothing will show up. I and techcrunch and others are treated completely different. I want a fancy user ID like them, not just for the user ID itself but to be able to embed channel videos.

Comment: With regard to what you wrote above, let me clarify that it's not the user ID per se that I am looking for, my main objective is to find a way to embed all my channel videos as in my original example, nothing else.

Comment: (Also I don't understand why I don't have a real user ID based on words in the first place when so many others seem to have it)

Comment: If you have a Youtube account, you have a google+ account, and therefore a proper username.

Comment: KerryWongBlog is not my blog, it's just an example.

Comment: It is incorrect that everyone with a YouTube account also has a Google+ account. I do, but not everyone does as you state above.

Comment: I have tried to use my Google+ username in the iframe snippet above already, did not work.

Comment: Well I'm stumped, hopefully someone else can drop by and answer your question.

Comment: Ok. Yes, it might be better, feels like we're stuck, which is often a sign that it's better to ask someone else or start working on something else.